# read files recursively from sub directories with spark from s3 or local filesystem

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to read files from a directory which contains many sub directories. The data is in S3 and I am trying to do this:

```
val rdd =sc.newAPIHadoopFile(data_loc,
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat],
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat],
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable])
```

this does not seem to work.

Appreciate the help

Comment: Have you tried just using `textFile("s3n://<root_dir>/*")` ?

Comment: yes , I tried that, does not work

Comment: Please post an example of how the directories are nested. There is probably a solution involving simple wildcards, like: `s3n://bucket/*/*/*`.

Comment: yes that works thank you. `s3n://bucket/root_dir/*/*/*` for year, month, date . But does something like this work: `s3n://bucket/root_dir/*/data/*/*/*` basically a directory in every sub directory ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

yes it works, took a while to get the individual blocks/splits though , basically a specific directory in every sub directory :
`s3n://bucket/root_dir/*/data/*/*/*`

Comment: This answer is not clear: what does "a specific directory in every sub directory" mean?  Your example does not show that either. thx!

Comment: s3n://bucket/root_dir/*/data/*/*/* in the above url , I am trying to read the dir data. The parent dir of data is variable and so I used "*". Hope that helps.

Comment: Sounds like a different use case than mine - which is "given a dir /some/hdfs/dir":  find all files underneath it.  The structure /some/hdfs/dir/*/*/*/* ."  does not work: hdfs -dfs returns an error on any of the directory entries it finds.

Comment: This works, but is dog slow. Apparently, the first `*` triggers an s3 list, then for each of the results, the next `*` triggers a list. The actual fetch is delayed while all of the listing occurs. Is there a single recursive pattern?

Answer (score -1):

ok, try this :

```
hadoop fs -lsr
drwxr-xr-x   - venuktangirala supergroup          0 2014-02-11 16:30 /user/venuktangirala/-p
drwxr-xr-x   - venuktangirala supergroup          0 2014-04-15 17:00 /user/venuktangirala/.Trash
drwx------   - venuktangirala supergroup          0 2015-02-11 16:16 /user/venuktangirala/.staging
-rw-rw-rw-   1 venuktangirala supergroup      19823 2013-10-24 14:34 /user/venuktangirala/data
drwxr-xr-x   - venuktangirala supergroup          0 2014-02-12 22:50 /user/venuktangirala/pandora
```

`-lsr` lists recursively, then parse the ones that do not start with "d"