# Recursively fetch file contents from subdirectories using sc.textFile

Tags: java, apache-spark

It seems that SparkContext textFile expects only files to be present in the given directory location - it does not either

- (a) recurse or
- (b) even *support* directories (tries to read directories as files)

Any suggestion how to structure a recursion - potentially simpler than creating the recursive file list / descent logic manually?

Here is the use case: files under

> /data/tables/my_table

I want to be able to read via an hdfs call all the files at all directory levels under that parent directory.

**UPDATE**

The sc.textFile() invokes the Hadoop FileInputFormat via the (subclass) TextInputFormat.  Inside the logic does exist to do the recursive directory reading - i.e. first detecting if an entry were a directory and if so then descending:

```
<!-- language: java -->
     for (FileStatus globStat: matches) {
218          if (globStat.isDir()) {
219            for(FileStatus stat: fs.listStatus(globStat.getPath(),
220                inputFilter)) {
221              result.add(stat);
222            }          
223          } else {
224            result.add(globStat);
225          }
226        }
```

However when invoking sc.textFile there are errors on directory entries: "not a file". This behavior is confusing - given the proper support appears to be in place for handling directories.

Comment: One possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914145/read-files-recursively-from-sub-directories-with-spark-from-s3-or-local-filesyst

Comment: @JustinPihony  Thanks I am not using S3 - so it is unclear if that answer applies.

Comment: Can you provide an example directory layout? Is the globbing syntax not sufficient? e.g. `textFile(/path/*/*)`

Comment: @NickChammas  No the globbing does not work: it does not descend and also any directory encountered generates an error "not a file"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I was looking at an old version of FileInputFormat..

**BEFORE** setting the recursive config **mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive**

```
scala> sc.textFile("dev/*").count
     java.io.IOException: Not a file: file:/shared/sparkup/dev/audit-release/blank_maven_build
```

The default is null/not set which is evaluated as "false":

```
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.get("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive")
res1: String = null
```

**AFTER:**

Now set the value :

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")
```

Now retry the recursive operation:

```
scala>sc.textFile("dev/*/*").count

..
res5: Long = 3481

So it works.
```

**Update**  added */* for full recursion per comment by @Ben

Comment: This is super helpful. It's also worth adding that you need an asterisk for each level. My data is stored more like `dev/<year>/<month>/<day>`. To get multiple months of data I need syntax like `sc.textFile("dev/2015/*/*").count`

Comment: Thx for that additional comment. Will update my post

Comment: I am using Spark 1.6.1 and didn't need an asterisk for each level.

Comment: Using Spark 1.6.2 (via pyspark) and getting an error: `AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'hadoopConfiguration'`

Comment: Ok, my bad. Apparently in Spark 1.6.2 you don't have to set this parameter. Seems to be the default.

Comment: **Wow!** Someone added a ***pro-bono*** bounty here. Never saw that before.

Comment: I tested this on `fileStream` API and it didn't work. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: I have the same problem. No Solution found yet with spark 2.3.2 all this recursive do not work

Answer (score 2):

I have found that these parameters must be set in the following way:

```
.set("spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories","true")
.set("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")
```