# Spark SQL "No input paths specified in job", but can printSchema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can read Json and `printSchema`, but running any actions fails (No input paths specified in job).

```
val sc = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext("local[*]", "shell")
val sqlCtx = new SQLContext(sc)
val input = sqlCtx.jsonFile("../data/tweets/")
input.printSchema
```

> root
>   |-- contributorsIDs: array (nullable = true)
>   |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
>   |-- createdAt: string (nullable = true)
>   ...

```
input.first
java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
```

Folder structure looks like:

- tweets

  - tweets_1444576960000

    - _SUCCESS
    - part-00000
  - tweets_1444577070000

    - _SUCCESS
    - part-00000

Notes:

- I am using Spark and Spark SQL version 1.5.0
- Executors are `local[*]` on same machine
- I tried replacing the file path with absolute path. Same error
- Json tweets were fetched using [databrick's example app here](https://github.com/databricks/reference-apps/blob/master/twitter_classifier/scala/src/main/scala/com/databricks/apps/twitter_classifier/Collect.scala)

Comment: If you want to try recursively fetching directories, there seems to be a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817940/recursively-fetch-file-contents-from-subdirectories-using-sc-textfile).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, problem solved by specifying the path like

```
val input = sqlCtx.jsonFile("../data/tweets/tweets_*/*")
```