# Reading multiple avro files into RDD from a nested directory structure

Tags: apache-spark, avro

suppose I have a directory which contains a bunch of avro files and I want to read them all in one shot. this code works fine

```
val path = "hdfs:///path/to/your/avro/folder"
val avroRDD = sc.hadoopFile[AvroWrapper[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord]](path)
```

However, if the folder contains subfolders and the avro files are in subfolders. then I get an error

```
5/10/30 14:57:47 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6, 
hadoop1): java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /folder/subfolder
```

Is there anyway I can read all the avros (even in subdirectories) into an RDD?

all avros have same schema and I am on spark 1.3.0

Edit::

Based on the suggestion below I executed this line in my spark shell

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")
```

and this solved the problem.... but now my code is very very slow and I don't understand what does a mapreduce setting have to do with spark.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817940/recursively-fetch-file-contents-from-subdirectories-using-sc-textfile) should help. It's just an input configuration issue.

Comment: This line solves the problem `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")` but now I am confused on what does spark have to do with mapreduce setting