# Spark - how does it distribute data around the nodes?

Tags: apache-spark

How does spark distribute data to workers?

Do the workers read from the data source, or does the driver reads it and sends it to workers? And when a worker needs data that is in another worker, do they communicate directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you use distributed input methods like [SparkContext.textFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#textFile(java.lang.String,%20int)) then workers read directly from your data source (or if you explicitly open HDFS files from inside worker task code then of course those will also occur on the workers).

If you manually read data in on your main driver program, and then used `SparkContext.parallelize`, then indeed your driver will be sending data to your workers.

Data dependencies from worker to worker are generally referred to as the [shuffle](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Shuffle+Internals); this type of worker-to-worker communication is in a lot of ways the heart of most big data processing systems, precisely because it's tricky to do efficiently and reliably. Conceptually you can treat it more-or-less as "communicating directly", but there may be a lot more going on under the hood depending on how the data dependency is taken on.

Comment: Dennis, that was very helpful. Do you have any reading recommendation on the subject? Thanks.

Comment: "https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Spark+Internals" should give you a start!!!

Comment: Still not clear to me how the workers coordinate which part of the file each of them reads when using SparkContext.textFile.

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817940/recursively-fetch-file-contents-from-subdirectories-using-sc-textfile) that explains how `sc.textFile` delegates through to a Hadoop `TextInputFormat`; a `TextInputFormat` does a `listStatus` to get a complete listing of files in a directory with their corresponding sizes, and then uses various split-sizing configuration settings to chop it up into an array of so-called "splits" which are just filename plus a byte-range in the filename. Spark the takes the splits and tells workers to grab a subset of the splits.

Comment: Any pointers on how the worker-worker communication happens? Is it via SSH? Should we explicitly ensure that all ports between workers are open? Should we also enable passwordless ssh between workers? Thank you.