# How do Spark Nodes communicate during a Shuffle?

Tags: apache-spark

I've seen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084293/spark-how-does-it-distribute-data-around-the-nodes) that Spark nodes effectively "communicate directly", but I'm less concerned with the theory and more with the implementation. [Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html) it shows, in the "###Encryption" section near the bottom of the page, that you can configure Spark to use a number of SSL protocols for security, which would suggest, to me at least, that it uses some form of HTTP(s) for communication. My question is effectively two parts: what protocol do Spark nodes use to communicate, and how is the data formatted for this transfer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spark uses RPC (Netty) to communicate between the executor processes. You can look into the [`NettyRpcEndpointRef`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rpc/netty/NettyRpcEnv.scala#L493) class to see that actual implementation.

For shuffling data, we start from the [`BlockManager`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManager.scala) which is responsible for providing data blocks. There is one per executor process. Internally a `BlockStoreShuffleReader` which manages the reads from different executors using a `SerializerManager`. This manager holds an actual serializer, which is defined by the `spark.serializer` property:

```
val serializer = instantiateClassFromConf[Serializer](
  "spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer")
logDebug(s"Using serializer: ${serializer.getClass}")
```

When the `BlockManager` attempts to read a block, it uses the serializer from that underlying configuration. It can be either a `KryoSerializer` or a `JavaSerializer`, depending on your setting.

Bottom line, for reading and writing shuffled data Spark uses the user defined serializer.

---

For task serialization, this is a little different.

Spark uses a variable called `closureSerializer`, which defaults to [`JavaSerializerInstance`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/serializer/JavaSerializer.scala#L93), meaning Java serialization. You can see this inside the [`DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/DAGScheduler.scala#L1010) method:

```
val taskBinaryBytes: Array[Byte] = stage match {
  case stage: ShuffleMapStage =>
    JavaUtils.bufferToArray(
      closureSerializer.serialize((stage.rdd, stage.shuffleDep): AnyRef))
  case stage: ResultStage =>
      JavaUtils.bufferToArray(closureSerializer.serialize((stage.rdd, stage.func): AnyRef))
}
```

The actual object that gets serialized and sent to each executor is called [`TaskDescription`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskDescription.scala):

```
def encode(taskDescription: TaskDescription): ByteBuffer = {
  val bytesOut = new ByteBufferOutputStream(4096)
  val dataOut = new DataOutputStream(bytesOut)

  dataOut.writeLong(taskDescription.taskId)
  dataOut.writeInt(taskDescription.attemptNumber)
  dataOut.writeUTF(taskDescription.executorId)
  dataOut.writeUTF(taskDescription.name)
  dataOut.writeInt(taskDescription.index)

  // Write files.
  serializeStringLongMap(taskDescription.addedFiles, dataOut)

  // Write jars.
  serializeStringLongMap(taskDescription.addedJars, dataOut)

  // Write properties.
  dataOut.writeInt(taskDescription.properties.size())
  taskDescription.properties.asScala.foreach { case (key, value) =>
    dataOut.writeUTF(key)
    // SPARK-19796 -- writeUTF doesn't work for long strings, which can happen for property values
    val bytes = value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    dataOut.writeInt(bytes.length)
    dataOut.write(bytes)
  }

  // Write the task. The task is already serialized, so write it directly to the byte buffer.
  Utils.writeByteBuffer(taskDescription.serializedTask, bytesOut)

  dataOut.close()
  bytesOut.close()
  bytesOut.toByteBuffer
}
```

And gets sent over RPC from the [`CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.launchTasks`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/cluster/CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala#L281) method:

```
executorData.executorEndpoint.send(LaunchTask(new SerializableBuffer(serializedTask)))
```

What I've showed so far talks about launching tasks. For shuffling data, Spark holds a `BlockStoreShuffleReader` which manages the reads from different executors.

Comment: Thank you very much! Couldn't have asked for a more informative and direct answer.

Comment: As a quick follow-up: I understand that Spark workers load input data directly from the filesystem when possible, but if the driver program loads the data first and hands it to the workers manually, would this also be done through RPC like you've described? Thanks.

Comment: The driver and workers communicate via RPC. Note that It is very unusual for the driver to load the data itself and distribute it to the workers.

Comment: For worker-worker communication, does RPC use ssh under the hood? I am trying to understand if passwordless ssh between driver-executor would suffice or if passwordless ssh between worker-worker also needs to be setup for worker-worker communication to happen.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks for the details. Would you mind if I ask how did you get such in-depth knowledge? Going through the source code or using some other resource?

Comment: @tharindu_DG Yes, I read the source code on multiple occasions :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Can you please address my comment? Thank you.