# Read all the files in the folder/subfolder in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

If we have a folder with multiple subfolders, to read the text files in the folder we can use `sc.textFile("folder/*/*.txt)`, but if we are not sure on the level of subfolders how to read the files recursively from folder and subfolders in spark?

I tried with `sc.textFile("folder/**/*.txt)` but it's not working and taking only immediate nested folder not all the subfolders(level).

Comment: keep only folder/*.txt  and check

Comment: "folder/*.txt" will consider the files available within the main directory not all the files from the subdirectories

Comment: Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817940/recursively-fetch-file-contents-from-subdirectories-using-sc-textfile. Does that help?

Comment: Did you try enabling the "mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive" conf ?

Comment: yes, I set the "mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", but still I am getting the same issue that its not considering the nested folders.