# PySpark Job throwing IOError

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have just pasted the long stacktrace for clarity in case someone has seen this error previously. I am trying to write a simple KNN job using pyspark on a hdfs cluster. I am using very few input files to perform the job so I don't think it's a memory (space). I do not do a broadcast in any part of my code. So it is surprising to me when the broadcast.py fails? I however do have python dictionaries that I have in shared memory without explicitly doing a broadcast.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on?

I have also pasted my entire code below (above the stacktrace).

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector
from pyspark import SparkContext
import glob
import sys
import time
import subprocess
from itertools import combinations
"""We create user and item indices starting from 0 to #users and 0 to #items respectively. This is done to store them in sparseVectors as dicts."""
def create_indices(inputdir):
    items=dict()
    user_id_to_idx=dict()
    user_idx_to_id=dict()
    item_idx_to_id=dict()
    item_id_to_idx=dict()
    item_idx=0
    user_idx=0

    cat=subprocess.Popen(["hadoop","fs","-cat","/user/hadoop/"+inputdir+"/*.txt"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in cat.stdout:
        toks=map(str,line.strip().split("\t"))
        try:
            user_id_to_idx[toks[1].strip()]
        except KeyError:
            if toks[1].strip()!=None:
                user_id_to_idx[toks[1].strip()]=user_idx
                user_idx_to_id[user_idx]=toks[1].strip()
                user_idx+=1
        try:
            item_id_to_idx[toks[0].strip()]
        except KeyError:
            if toks[0].strip()!=None:
                item_id_to_idx[toks[0].strip()]=item_idx
                item_idx_to_id[item_idx]=toks[0].strip()
                item_idx+=1
    return user_idx_to_id,user_id_to_idx,item_idx_to_id,item_id_to_idx,user_idx,item_idx

def concat_helper(a,b):
    if(a!= None and b!=None):
        print a,b,a.update(b)
        temp=dict()
        temp.update(a)
        temp.update(b)
        return temp
    elif a!=None:
        return a
    elif b!=None:
        return b

# pass in the hdfs path to the input files and the spark context.
def runKNN(inputdir,sc,user_id_to_idx,item_id_to_idx):
    rdd_text=sc.textFile(inputdir)
    try:
        new_rdd = rdd_text.map(lambda x: (item_id_to_idx[str(x.strip().split("\t")[0])],{user_id_to_idx[str(x.strip().split("\t")[1])]:1})).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: concat_helper(x,y)).sortByKey()
    except KeyError:
        print item_id_to_idx.keys()
        pass
    return new_rdd

if __name__=="__main__":
    sc = SparkContext()
    u_idx_to_id,u_id_to_idx,i_idx_to_id,i_id_to_idx,u_idx,i_idx=create_indices(sys.argv[1])

    u_idx_to_id_b=sc.broadcast(u_idx_to_id)
    u_id_to_idx_b=sc.broadcast(u_id_to_idx)
    i_idx_to_idx_b=sc.broadcast(i_idx_to_id)
    i_id_to_idx_b=sc.broadcast(i_id_to_idx)
    num_users=sc.broadcast(u_idx)
    num_items=sc.broadcast(i_idx)
    item_dict_rdd=runKNN(sys.argv[1],sc,u_id_to_idx,i_id_to_idx)

    item_dict_rdd_new=item_dict_rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],SparseVector(i_idx,x[1])))
    item_dict_rdd_new.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://output_path")
    #dot_products_rdd=map(lambda (x,y): (x,y),combinations(item_dict_rdd_new.map(lambda x: x),2))
    dot_products_rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://output_path_2")
```

Stack Trace:

```
15/05/19 13:44:11 WARN spark.SparkConf: Setting 'spark.executor.extraClassPath' to '/home/hadoop/spark/conf:/home/hadoop/conf:/home/hadoop/spark/classpath/emr/*:/home/hadoop/spark/classpath/emrfs/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-lzo.jar' as a work-around.
15/05/19 13:44:11 WARN spark.SparkConf: Setting 'spark.driver.extraClassPath' to '/home/hadoop/spark/conf:/home/hadoop/conf:/home/hadoop/spark/classpath/emr/*:/home/hadoop/spark/classpath/emrfs/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-lzo.jar' as a work-around.
15/05/19 13:44:11 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop
15/05/19 13:44:11 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop
15/05/19 13:44:11 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hadoop); users with modify permissions: Set(hadoop)
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-.ec2.internal:38952]
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 38952.
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /mnt/spark/spark-7898e98c-1685-450b-a47a-2fbede361cf3/blockmgr-c3ce83af-b195-4ec9-8e1f-8d71ee0589b1
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.4 MB
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /mnt/spark/spark-94ffb583-1f85-4505-8d4d-1f104d612be6/httpd-8e8e619f-c4e6-4813-ac0d-b8793e7ff84d
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:41841
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 41841.
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/05/19 13:44:12 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://ip.ec2.internal:4040
15/05/19 13:44:13 INFO util.Utils: Copying /mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py to /mnt/spark/spark-afbde2d3-d58a-468f-b84f-c131ecd708cd/userFiles-6918221d-be13-4ce6-adbc-a4fcbd787996/knn.py
15/05/19 13:44:13 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added file file:/mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py at file:/mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py with timestamp 1432043053065
15/05/19 13:44:13 INFO executor.Executor: Starting executor ID <driver> on host localhost
15/05/19 13:44:13 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ip-.ec2.internal:38952/user/HeartbeatReceiver
15/05/19 13:44:13 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 44689
15/05/19 13:44:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/05/19 13:44:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager localhost:44689 with 265.4 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 44689)
15/05/19 13:44:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
7412 ==================================================
55134 ==================================================
15/05/19 13:44:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(253503) called with curMem=0, maxMem=278302556
15/05/19 13:44:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 247.6 KB, free 265.2 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(19226) called with curMem=253503, maxMem=278302556
15/05/19 13:44:16 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 18.8 KB, free 265.1 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:16 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:44689 (size: 18.8 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:16 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
15/05/19 13:44:16 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
15/05/19 13:44:17 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(296) called with curMem=272729, maxMem=278302556
15/05/19 13:44:17 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 296.0 B, free 265.1 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:17 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2504167) called with curMem=273025, maxMem=278302556
15/05/19 13:44:17 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.4 MB, free 262.8 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:44689 (size: 2.4 MB, free: 263.0 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_1_piece0
15/05/19 13:44:17 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at PythonRDD.scala:399
15/05/19 13:44:17 INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library from the embedded binaries
15/05/19 13:44:17 INFO lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 77cfa96225d62546008ca339b7c2076a3da91578]
15/05/19 13:44:17 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 5
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(296) called with curMem=2777192, maxMem=278302556
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 296.0 B, free 262.8 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2506273) called with curMem=2777488, maxMem=278302556
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.4 MB, free 260.4 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on localhost:44689 (size: 2.4 MB, free: 260.6 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_2_piece0
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from reduceByKey at /mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py:59
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: sortByKey at /mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py:59
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 4 (reduceByKey at /mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py:59)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (sortByKey at /mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py:59) with 5 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 1(sortByKey at /mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py:59)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(Stage 0)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(Stage 0)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (PairwiseRDD[4] at reduceByKey at /mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py:59), which has no missing parents
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(5288) called with curMem=5283761, maxMem=278302556
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.2 KB, free 260.4 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3048) called with curMem=5289049, maxMem=278302556
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.0 KB, free 260.4 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on localhost:44689 (size: 3.0 KB, free: 260.6 MB)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_3_piece0
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 3 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:839
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 5 missing tasks from Stage 0 (PairwiseRDD[4] at reduceByKey at /mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py:59)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 5 tasks
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, ANY, 1407 bytes)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, ANY, 1407 bytes)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost, ANY, 1407 bytes)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost, ANY, 1407 bytes)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, localhost, ANY, 1407 bytes)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO executor.Executor: Fetching file:/mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py with timestamp 1432043053065
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO util.Utils: /mnt/user/spark_practice/knn.py has been previously copied to /mnt/spark/spark-afbde2d3-d58a-468f-b84f-c131ecd708cd/userFiles-6918221d-be13-4ce6-adbc-a4fcbd787996/knn.py
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://10.64.10.43:9000/user/hadoop/user/practice/knn/inputfile
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://10.64.10.43:9000/user/hadoop/user/practice/knn/inputfile2
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://10.64.10.43:9000/user/hadoop/user/practice/knn/inputfile3
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://10.64.10.43:9000/user/hadoop/user/practice/knn/inputfile4
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://10.64.10.43:9000/user/hadoop/user/practice/knn/inputfile5
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
15/05/19 13:44:18 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
15/05/19 13:44:19 INFO metrics.MetricsSaver: MetricsConfigRecord disabledInCluster: false instanceEngineCycleSec: 60 clusterEngineCycleSec: 60 disableClusterEngine: false
15/05/19 13:44:19 INFO metrics.MetricsSaver: Created MetricsSaver j-24SI04Y9O1ZVF:i-58ae838e:SparkSubmit:24683 period:60 /mnt/var/em/raw/i-58ae838e_20150519_SparkSubmit_24683_raw.bin
15/05/19 13:44:19 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 90, in main
    command = pickleSer.loads(command.value)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 106, in value
    self._value = self.load(self._path)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 87, in load
    with open(path, 'rb', 1 << 20) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/spark/spark-ea646b94-3f68-47a5-8e1c-b23ac0799718/pyspark-7d842875-fae2-4563-b367-92d89d292b60/tmpjlEm1f'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/05/19 13:44:19 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 90, in main
    command = pickleSer.loads(command.value)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 106, in value
    self._value = self.load(self._path)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 87, in load
    with open(path, 'rb', 1 << 20) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/spark/spark-ea646b94-3f68-47a5-8e1c-b23ac0799718/pyspark-7d842875-fae2-4563-b367-92d89d292b60/tmpjlEm1f'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/05/19 13:44:19 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 90, in main
    command = pickleSer.loads(command.value)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 106, in value
    self._value = self.load(self._path)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 87, in load
    with open(path, 'rb', 1 << 20) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/spark/spark-ea646b94-3f68-47a5-8e1c-b23ac0799718/pyspark-7d842875-fae2-4563-b367-92d89d292b60/tmpjlEm1f'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/05/19 13:44:19 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 90, in main
    command = pickleSer.loads(command.value)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 106, in value
    self._value = self.load(self._path)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 87, in load
    with open(path, 'rb', 1 << 20) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/spark/spark-ea646b94-3f68-47a5-8e1c-b23ac0799718/pyspark-7d842875-fae2-4563-b367-92d89d292b60/tmpjlEm1f'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/05/19 13:44:19 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 90, in main
    command = pickleSer.loads(command.value)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 106, in value
    self._value = self.load(self._path)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 87, in load
    with open(path, 'rb', 1 << 20) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/spark/spark-ea646b94-3f68-47a5-8e1c-b23ac0799718/pyspark-7d842875-fae2-4563-b367-92d89d292b60/tmpjlEm1f
```

'

Answer (score 0):

you can read files that match the patterns and run a flatMap on the folder. data_loc= "/user/hadoop/"+inputdir+"/*.txt"
refer to this: [read files recursively from sub directories with spark from s3 or local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914145/read-files-recursively-from-sub-directories-with-spark-from-s3-or-local-filesyst)

When you apply flatMap on that data_loc, keys are the file names and values are the content of the file.

You don't need to run a command line process.

Hope it helps